# Como exibir o valor de uma query em C?

Tags: c

Refazendo a pergunta:

Tenho uma tabela no Mysql onde preciso exibir o nome da pessoa assim que ela digita o seu RG.
Estou fazendo um código onde apenas tento fazer a pesquisa para ver se esta buscando normalmente, mas não consigo exibir este valor na tela.

Segue o código:

```
int main(){

    MYSQL conexao;
    int res;
    int esco = 2;
    char query[100];
    mysql_init(&conexao);
    if ( mysql_real_connect(&conexao, "localhost", "root", "", "teatro", 0, NULL, 0) ){
        sprintf(query,"select tb_aluno_nome from tb_aluno where tb_aluno_rg = '999999999';");
        res = mysql_query(&conexao,query);
        if (!res)
            printf("nome: %i",res);
        system("pause");
        return(0);

    }
}
```

Comment: coloque o código do que já foi feito ou explique melhor a situação, para ajudar a visualizar o seu problema

Comment: Talvez tirando o `!` de `if (!res)`... o `!` significa "negativo" (zero, null ou vazio), que me parece ser o contrário do que deseja.

Comment: Na verdade, o `!` significa _false_

Comment: Na verdade, o `!` significa *not*, não? :-)  -> [C Operators](https://www.w3schools.in/c-tutorial/operators/)

Answer (score 0):

Testa ai meu bom!

```
int main() {
   MYSQL conexao;
   int res;
   int esco = 2;
   char query[100];
   mysql_init(&conexao);
   if ( mysql_real_connect(&conexao, "localhost", "root", "", "teatro", 0, NULL, 0) ){
       sprintf(query, "select tb_aluno_nome from tb_aluno where tb_aluno_rg = '999999999';");
       res = mysql_query(&conexao,query);
       if (res) {
           campos = mysql_fetch_fields(res);
           for (i=0; i < mysql_num_fields(res); i++) {
               printf("%s", (campos[i]).name);
           }
       }
   }
   mysql_close(&conexao);
   system("pause");
   return(0);
}
```